# Connecting two devices with different scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm implementing a game in Unity and I have a problem that I need advise for. I want to connect a tablet and a computer. The scene that is on the computer is supposed so send an event once an object is collected so that a special scene can be shown on the tablet. So based on what is happening on the computer there is a different scene shown on the tablet.

I only have no idea how to achieve that.

Comment: This question is pretty broad ... is simply having a TCP connection an option?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create 2 different applications (for desktop and mobile). Second, you need to determine what protocol you want to connect desktop app and mobile app. The easiest way to implement this I think by using WebSocket/internet but not HTTP. Yes, you need to write code for the backend so it likes creating 3 different apps. But you can use firebase to simplify this process.

I recommended you use firestore from firebase. Connect booth app to firestore. When desktop app sends data to firestore, firebase will automatically notify mobile app and send that data. But you need to figure out yourself how to pair a desktop app and a mobile app otherwise, your firestore will receive data from all connected desktop app and send the same data to all connected mobile app.

This tutorial to use firestore:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5h1bVGhuRk

But before that, you need to add firebase to your project before you add firestore:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

You can use any wireless protocol available. You can even use Bluetooth if you want your app offline. But I don't know how to use Bluetooth...